# Radio Button setOnClickListener does not run completely

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-button

I am working on a mobile app in which I have used the radio buttons. The strange thing is that the radio button's setOnClickListener does not run complete code. Here is the code of my radio Button

```
radioButtonWeekly.setOnClickListener {
            btnSelectWeek.isEnabled = true
            btnSelectWeek.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
            btnSelectMonth.isEnabled = false
            btnSelectMonth.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)

            Log.i("${PerformanceFragment::class.java.simpleName}: ", "Selected Week No: ${selectedWeekNo}")
            }
```

Only the above four statements run. The last statement (Log.i) does not run. In fact, any statement below the above four statements does not run. Please explain what is going on wrong?

Comment: How do you know they don't run? Have you tried checking in debug?

Comment: Yes, I've checked in debug. No statement is executed except the first four statements.

Comment: By only looking at the code you posted, there should be no reason to only execute the first four statements. So the issue is probably somewhere else.

Comment: I have tried this code on another system and it works fine. I think three is some issue with Android  Studio.

Answer (score 0):

first create radio group

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pirates"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ninjas"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

then for handle radio buttons

```
fun onRadioButtonClicked(view: View) {
    if (view is RadioButton) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        val checked = view.isChecked

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        when (view.getId()) {
            R.id.radio_pirates ->
                if (checked) {
                    // Pirates are the best
                }
            R.id.radio_ninjas ->
                if (checked) {
                    // Ninjas rule
                }
        }
    }
}
```

source https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton

Comment: or use RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: I have also used the OnCheckedChangeListener mentioned above. But no luck.....